# Create nested child JSON

Tags: c#, json

How can I create this nested child json in C#? I am unable to figure out how to add into list to child nestedly. I am using [this](http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/8375092).

**JSON**

```
 {
"name": "Top Level",
"parent": "null",
"children": [
  {
    "name": "Level 2: A",
    "parent": "Top Level",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "Son of A",
        "parent": "Level 2: A"
        ,
         "children": [
      {
        "name": "Son of A",
        "parent": "Level 2: A"

      },
      {
        "name": "Daughter of A",
        "parent": "Level 2: A"
      }
    ]

      },
      {
        "name": "Daughter of A",
        "parent": "Level 2: A"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Level 2: B",
    "parent": "Top Level"
  }
 ]
}
```

**Diagramatic Representation of Root and Child**

[image]

**Class**

```
 public class d3_mitch
{


    public string  name { get; set; }


    public string parent { get; set; }

    public List<d3_mitch> children { get; set; }
}
```

**What I am doing**

```
  d3_mitch d3 = new d3_mitch();
        d3.id = 1;
        d3.name = "Root";
        d3.type = "Root";
        d3.description = "abc blah blah";
        d3.children = new List<d3_mitch>()
        {

              new d3_mitch() { name = "Carnivores", type = "Type", id = 2, description = "Diet consists solely of animal materials",
            children=new List<d3_mitch>(){ new d3_mitch() { id= 3 ,name="Felidae",type="Family",description="Also known as cats"} }
           }
        };
```

**Now Problem Is**

How can I add child to each list of parent having id = N?

**Like this**

```
 d3.children = new List<d3_mitch>()
        {

              new d3_mitch() { name = "Carnivores", type = "Type", id = 2, description = "Diet consists solely of animal materials",
            children=new List<d3_mitch>(){ new d3_mitch() { id= 3 ,name="Felidae",type="Family",description="Also known as cats",



           //This one
            children=new List<d3_mitch>(){ new d3_mitch() { id = 4, name = "Felidae4", type = "Family", description = "Also known as cats" } }



            } }
           }
        };
```

Comment: You mean you don't know how to add items to the `children` list? Is it not simply `mitchEntity.children = new List<d3_mitch>(); mitchEntity.Children.Add(nestedEntity1); mitchEntity.Children.Add(nestedEntity2);`?

Comment: no , I mean a parent has list of child then foreach child there could be more childs and then on these each child could be more and so on ...this is nested scenario

Comment: OK, but the confusion isn't clear. You can build child nodes, and then build the parents, right?

Comment: yes I can set child as List<d3_mitch> then on each item of this list I have to add more child

Comment: Please can you explain in concrete terms, ideally by providing an example, where you are stuck? I don't see how having a parent `d3_mitch` which you have to add children to, is any different to having a child of that parent which you have to add its own children to. In that scenario the first level child becomes a parent of the second level children. At the end of the day, you're still only dealing with `d3_mitch` objects.

Comment: Since neither of the current answers are acceptable: why aren't they acceptable? What is it that they can't do that you require to resolve this issue? Both allow you to assemble a tree of any size and complexity, so you'll need to provide more information as to why this isn't acceptable.

Answer (score 5):

Since your class definition differs in your examples, I've made my own for the purposes of this example:

```
public class MyNode
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<MyNode> Nodes { get; set; }

    public MyNode()
    {
        Nodes = new List<MyNode>();
    }
}
```

Next we can create a flat list of nodes with their relationships defined by their ids:

```
var rootNode = new MyNode() { ParentId = -1, Id = 1, Name = "Root" };
var nodes = new [] {
    rootNode,
    new MyNode() { ParentId = 1, Id = 2, Name = "ChildA" },
    new MyNode() { ParentId = 1, Id = 3, Name = "ChildB" },
    new MyNode() { ParentId = 2, Id = 4, Name = "ChildA.A" },
    new MyNode() { ParentId = 2, Id = 5, Name = "ChildA.B" },
    new MyNode() { ParentId = 3, Id = 6, Name = "ChildB.A" },
    new MyNode() { ParentId = 3, Id = 7, Name = "ChildB.B" }
};
```

Then we can go through each item looking up its parent and adding it to its parent's child list:

```
var nodeDict = nodes.ToDictionary(n => n.Id);
foreach (var item in nodes)
{
    MyNode parentNode = null;
    if (item.ParentId == -1 || !nodeDict.TryGetValue(item.ParentId, out parentNode)) // we don't want to look up the root node since it doesn't have a parent. you might want to add error handling if the parent node isn't found
    {
        continue;
    }

    parentNode.Nodes.Add(item);
}
```

And then we can serialize the result:

```
Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(rootNode, Formatting.Indented));
```

[Try it online](https://rextester.com/NBGNS76485)

---

A slightly more complicated approach using a similar technique is to create a "builder":

```
public interface IRootHierarchyBuilder 
{
    IHierarchyBuilder AddRootNode(MyNode rootNode);
}

public interface IHierarchyBuilder
{
    IHierarchyBuilder AddNode(MyNode childNode);
    MyNode Build();
}

public class HierarchyBuilder : IRootHierarchyBuilder, IHierarchyBuilder
{
    private readonly IDictionary<int, MyNode> _nodes;
    private MyNode _rootNode;

    private HierarchyBuilder()
    {
        _nodes = new Dictionary<int, MyNode>();
    }

    public static IRootHierarchyBuilder Create()
    {
        return new HierarchyBuilder();
    }

    IHierarchyBuilder IRootHierarchyBuilder.AddRootNode(MyNode rootNode)
    {
        if (_rootNode != null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Root node already exists.");
        }
        _rootNode = rootNode;
        _nodes[rootNode.Id] = rootNode;
        return this;
    }

    IHierarchyBuilder IHierarchyBuilder.AddNode(MyNode childNode)
    {
        if (_rootNode == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Root node not set.");
        }

        if (_nodes.ContainsKey(childNode.Id))
        {
            throw new Exception("This child has already been added.");
        }

        MyNode parentNode;
        if (!_nodes.TryGetValue(childNode.ParentId, out parentNode))
        {
            throw new KeyNotFoundException("Parent node not found.");
        }
        parentNode.Nodes.Add(childNode);

        _nodes[childNode.Id] = childNode;
        return this;
    }

    MyNode IHierarchyBuilder.Build()
    {
        if (_rootNode == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Root node not set.");
        }
        return _rootNode;            
    }
}
```

Which you can then use like so:

```
var rootNode = HierarchyBuilder.Create()
    .AddRootNode(new MyNode() { Id = 1, ParentId = -1, Name = "Root" })
    .AddNode(new MyNode() { Id = 2, ParentId = 1, Name = "ChildA" })
    .AddNode(new MyNode() { Id = 3, ParentId = 1, Name = "ChildB" })
    .AddNode(new MyNode() { Id = 4, ParentId = 2, Name = "ChildA.A" })
    .AddNode(new MyNode() { Id = 5, ParentId = 2, Name = "ChildA.B" })
    .AddNode(new MyNode() { Id = 6, ParentId = 3, Name = "ChildB.A" })
    .AddNode(new MyNode() { Id = 7, ParentId = 3, Name = "ChildB.B" })
    .Build();
```

And again, we can serialize the result:

```
Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(rootNode, Formatting.Indented));
```

[Try it online](https://rextester.com/QCPFJW35828)

Comment: giving you up vote but @john still  "Name": "ChildA.B" has no child in your example, my example shows 3 level child. Root>child>child>child

Comment: I think that's an issue for you to overcome. _It's not a code issue._ Again: ChildA.B having a child is no different to ChildA having a child. You just have to have the right ids in place to form the relationship. The code can make as deep a relationship as you like.

Comment: [Here is a deeper example](https://rextester.com/JZCTVG54895) using _the exact same code_ and one using the [builder example](https://rextester.com/ROND81630).

Comment: ok @john thank you very much for your effort , vote up from me

Answer (score 5):

@John has already shown a couple of automated ways of how to accomplish this, perhaps you'll see the pattern more clearly if we construct the tree by hand.

First, a couple of pointers:

1. Name your classes meaningfully, `d3_mitch` sounds like something from the next Star Wars movie.
2. C# properties start with Capital letters by convention.

Note your diagrammatic representation would also benefit from a better naming convention. As it stands the node `C1R3` appears at two places in the tree, which is impossible as trees don't allow cycles. You'd need to use a graph for that. Anyway, I created a new `Node` with the same name just to resemble the diagram.

Two options depending on the class representation, and how the data is fed:

1. Through Constructor Injection

The node class

```cs
public class Node
{
    public Node(int id, int parentId, string name, List<Node> children)
    {
        Id = id;
        ParentId = parentId;
        Name = name;
        Children = children;
    }

    public int Id { get; }
    public int ParentId { get; }
    public string Name { get; }
    public List<Node> Children { get; }
}
```

The tree assembly by hand

```cs
var tree =
    new Node(1, -1, "R", new List<Node>
    {
        new Node(2, 1, "C1R1", new List<Node>()),
        new Node(3, 1, "C2R2", new List<Node>()),
        new Node(4, 1, "C3R3", new List<Node>
        {
            new Node(5, 4, "C1R3", new List<Node>()),
            new Node(6, 4, "C2R3", new List<Node>
            {
                new Node(7, 6, "C1R3", new List<Node>())
            })
        })
    });
```

2. By setting Properties

The node class

```cs
public class Node
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Node> Children { get; set; }
}
```

The tree assembly by hand

```cs
var tree =
    new Node
    {
        Id = 1,
        ParentId = -1,
        Name = "R",
        Children = new List<Node>
        {
            new Node
            {
                Id = 2,
                ParentId = 1,
                Name = "C1R1",
                Children = new List<Node>()
            },
            new Node
            {
                Id = 3,
                ParentId = 1,
                Name = "C2R2",
                Children = new List<Node>()
            },
            new Node
            {
                Id = 4,
                ParentId = 1,
                Name = "C3R3",
                Children = new List<Node>
                {
                    new Node
                    {
                        Id = 5,
                        ParentId = 4,
                        Name = "C1R3",
                        Children = new List<Node>()
                    },
                    new Node
                    {
                        Id = 6,
                        ParentId = 4,
                        Name = "C2R3",
                        Children = new List<Node>
                        {
                            new Node
                            {
                                Id = 7,
                                ParentId = 6,
                                Name = "C1R3",
                                Children = new List<Node>()
                            },
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
        }
    };
```

Comment: but the question is how come the depth can be added to list ?

Comment: @Taha the issue here isn't clear. Turning your question on its head: what is the issue you're experiencing with adding depth? Do you mean you want a numeric value like "1" or "4" according to which level the item is on? You won't get the answer you seek until you explain more clearly what you're trying to do, since myself and Funk have already provided several ways you can achieve what you are supposedly trying to do.